# Jni Example in Eclipse

Tags: java-native-interface

Hi while trying out jni example in this link http://wendro.blogspot.com/2010/03/jni-example-eclipse-dev-cpp.html?showComment=1309930446765#c5048550711511727724 
with eclipse Helios windows xp am getting this error in eclipse console

"error: cannot access MyFirstWrapper, 
 class file for MyFirstWrapper not found,
 javadoc: error - Class MyFirstWrapper not found.
 Error: No classes were specified on the command line. Try -help."

what i have to do..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, set your run configuration's Working Directory to the project's bin.  in the arguments, set flag -d to change where the output file goes to your cpp folder. For example:

```
Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/ProjectRoot/bin}
Arguments: -d ${workspace_loc:/ProjectRoot/cpp} full.package.name.path.to.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks i only got the answer
i did like this i got a jni header file generated inside cpp folder

In Eclipse Run Tools, External Tools Configurations,

Name:Jni

Location:My javah.exe location
D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javah.exe

Working Directory: my javah file location
${workspace_loc:/jni_hello_world/cpp}

And the most important point is inside Arguments we have to give first as our .class location then jni command like below

-classpath E:\Workspace\JNI\jni_hello_world\bin
-jni MyFirstWrapper